# How to clean cache of flutter project?

Tags: flutter, data-cleaning, rebuild

How to clean cache of flutter project?

Answer (score 1):

> You can run "flutter clean" in terminal it will remove the cached build folder

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

should do what you want.

> The pub cache command works with the system cache.
>
> The `pub cache repair` command performs a clean reinstall of all
> hosted and git packages in the system cache.

[source](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in terminal "flutter clean"